# how to do the read more capability in xaml

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I want to do this in xaml.
 [image: ...read more]

I hope somebody can help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only option I can think of is to put the text with `TextTrimming` set to WordEllipsis, and have a second textblock. then in `onloaded` check the `text` property to see if the last characters are `...`

but i'm not even sure getting the text will retrieve text after the ellipsis is added.

one option I thought would be to create a custom ellipsis, or to to use some ontrimmed event, but they are not available.

Comment: I used the TextTrimming set to WordEllipsis and Binded the text to a tooltip so that the whole text can still be seen upon hover of the textblock.